# Text frame background in ConTeXT

Tags: context, backgrounds

Is is possible to add an image/pattern background in a text frame in ConTeXT?

What I had in mind was using:

`\startframedtext[background=mybackground]`

So that `mybackground` would be either defined by an `overlay` and/or a `layer`.

```
\defineoverlay[mybackground][\externalfigure[cow][width=\overlaywidth,height=\overlayheight]]

\starttext


\startframedtext[middle][frame=off,topframe=on,bottomframe=on,framecolor=darkgray,rulethickness=4pt,
background=mybackground, % doesn't work
width=.8\makeupwidth]
\input knuth
\stopframedtext
\stoptext
```

Comment: You have to put `\externalfigure` inside curly brackets: `\defineoverlay[mybackground][{\externalfigure...}]`

Comment: Square brackets are not recognized as grouping characters by TeX, so they don't nest.  The macro `\def\foo[#1]{...}` called with `\foo[ab[cd]ef]` will only receive `ab[cd` as its first argument.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio: Could you please post your comment as an answer